# String splitting with different character

Tags: java, string, split

i think it is a weird question. So here is my splitting:

```
String s = "asd#asd";
String[] raw1 = s.split("#"); // this has size of two raw[0] = raw[1] = "asd"
```

However,

```
String s = "asd$asd";
String[] raw2 = s.split("$"); // this has size of ONE
```

raw2 is not splitted. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Split takes a regular expression

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `split()` takes a *regexp*, and `$` indicates the end-of-line. If you need to split on a character that is actually a regexp metacharacter, then you'll need to escape it.

See [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for the regexp metacharacters.

You may find that [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is more appropriate for your needs. This will take a *list* of characters that you should split on, and it won't interpret them as regular expression metacharacters. However it's a little more verbose and unweildy to use. As Nandkumar notes below, the latest docs states that it is discouraged in new code.

Comment: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape it:

```
String s = "asd$asd";
String[] raw2 = s.split("\\$"); // this has size of TWO
```

Comment: You need to further escape that \$ - i.e. \\$

Answer (score 3):

Because `split()` takes a regex and `$` matches the end of a line.

You have to escape it :

```
s.split("\\$");
```

See [Pattern documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information on regexes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special character, make it

```
s.split("\\$");
```